# Partition pruning issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I’m joining 2 tables. Pruning is happening on table 1 but not on table 2 even though there is an outer join.

Example:

```
select *
from   table1 t1, table2 t2
where  t1.sk in (select sk from filter_table)
and    t2.sk(+) = t1.sk
```

When I check the plan and noticed t1 table has KEY partition scan, but T2 is scanning all the partition(~4500). so the query is taking more than 4hrs just to pull 50 recs.

Is there any way to force the pruning on table 2 as well?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: First you would better to stop this paleolithic join syntax and make explicit joins only

Comment: Table definitions and sample data would really help. What are the partition keys for t1 and t2? I'm guessing `sk` I suppose.

Comment: Yes sk is the partition keys on both the table. but t2.sk(+) = t1.sk join (old/new) way matter?

Answer (score 0):

Without more data it is hard to say for sure what the problem can be. I have rewritten the query for clarity and with a simple test schema I get pruning for both tables with Oracle 12c (I don't have 11g handy). The first with key and the second with Bloom Filter (:BF0000 in the plan).

```
select t1.*, t2.*
  from filter_table ft
  join table1 t1 on t1.sk = ft.sk
  left outer join table2 t2 on t2.sk = ft.sk;
```

Be sure to gather statistics for all three tables! Often when the optimizer seems to be stupid it is because the statistics are missing or not up to date.

Comment: thanks ewramner, The actually query is pretty big with lot of join. without making any changes to stats will try to rewrite the query and give a shot